# Changed Blocks APIs for Google Compute Persistent Disk Snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-persistent-disk

I am looking for an API similar to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/APIReference/API_ListChangedBlocks.html

Does GCP already have this in some form or has anything been announced?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/snapshots/get?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22test-repo-rnd%22%2C%22snapshot%22%3A%22snapshot-3%22%7D) for Snapshot API and ‘downloadBytes’ field might be similar thing you are looking for as it shows the chaged-blocks of bytes of a VM snapshot in two points in time.